# insert query for c# using olebd connection doesnt work

Tags: c#

```
    string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 ;" + "Data Source=D:\\it101\\LoginForm\\App_Data\\registration.mdb";

    string query = "INSERT INTO registration values (adsdsa,adsadsa,87987,dasdsa)";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connection);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query,con);

    DataSet ds =new DataSet();


    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
```

Comment: If you make an "insert into", wath do you expect into dataset?

Comment: Where are you executing your command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for insert

```
string queryString = "INSERT INTO registration values ('adsdsa','adsadsa',87987,'dasdsa')";
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connection))
using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

when you load data

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connection))
using(var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from registration", con)
{
  DataSet ds =new DataSet();
  adapter.Fill(ds);
  GridView1.DataSource = ds;
  GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to quote your string values -

```
 string query = "INSERT INTO registration values ('adsdsa','adsadsa',87987,'dasdsa')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the insert line with this

```
string query = "INSERT INTO registration values ('adsdsa','adsadsa',87987,'dasdsa')";
```

Answer (score 0):

After connection open();

Add this
cmd.open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

mean while passing data into the value add quote like  this
insert into tablename values ('data1','data2')
 i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you please try this:**

```
string query = "INSERT INTO registration values ('adsdsa','adsadsa',87987,'dasdsa');
```

Hope this helps..